# Creating a List to average my output numbers

Tags: python, list

I'm writing a code for grading and I have the user input 5 grades, then it will give them the grade letter. At the end of the 5 inputs I would like it to show the students grade point average.

```
def grades():


    grade = int(raw_input("Enter the student's grade: "))

    A = 'A'
    B = 'B'
    C = 'C'
    D = 'D'
    F = 'F'
    if grade >= 90:
        print A
    elif grade >= 80:
        print B
    elif grade >= 70:
        print C
    elif grade >= 60:
        print D
    else: F

    grade = int(raw_input("Enter the student's second grade: "))

    A = 'A'
    B = 'B'
    C = 'C'
    D = 'D'
    F = 'F'
    if grade >= 90:
        print A
    elif grade >= 80:
        print B
    elif grade >= 70:
        print C
    elif grade >= 60:
        print D
    else: F

    grade = int(raw_input("Enter the student's third grade: "))

    A = 'A'
    B = 'B'
    C = 'C'
    D = 'D'
    F = 'F'
    if grade >= 90:
        print A
    elif grade >= 80:
        print B
    elif grade >= 70:
        print C
    elif grade >= 60:
        print D
    else: print F

    grade = int(raw_input("Enter the student's fourth grade: "))

    A = 'A'
    B = 'B'
    C = 'C'
    D = 'D'
    F = 'F'
    if grade >= 90:
        print A
    elif grade >= 80:
        print B
    elif grade >= 70:
        print C
    elif grade >= 60:
        print D
    else: print F

    grade = int(raw_input("Enter the student's fifth grade: "))

    A = 'A'
    B = 'B'
    C = 'C'
    D = 'D'
    F = 'F'
    if grade >= 90:
        print A
    elif grade >= 80:
        print B
    elif grade >= 70:
        print C
    elif grade >= 60:
        print D
    else: print F

grades()
```

Any and all help would be appreciated. Looking for both grade number and letter grade average.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! You seem to be asking for someone to write some code for you. Stack Overflow is a question and answer site, not a code-writing service. Please [see here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) to learn how to write effective questions.

Comment: Wow.... What's the question? What have you tried?

Comment: Why do you redefine `A`, `B`, `C`, `D`, `E` and `F` 5 times with the same value? And why don't you use a loop? What would you do if someone requested you to enter 50 grades? Copy your existing code 10 times?

Answer (score 1):

Not sure what the question is and not going to write code for you so here is some simple pseudo code.

```
int average
for loop loops 5 times
    ask for each grade
    average += grade
average = average / times looped
check average against letter grade values
print average + letter grade
```

You already have most of this so I am not sure what the problem you are having is.